# Parsing json like data using php

Tags: php, javascript, json, web-crawler

I have some Json like data got crawling a URL

```
[[["oppl.lr",[,,,,,,,,,,,[[[[[,"A Google User"]
,,,,1]
,3000,,,"Double tree was ok, it wasnt super fancy or anything. Its good for families and  just relaxing by the pool. Service was good, and rooms were kept neat.","a year ago",["http://www.ma..",,1],,"","",""]
]
,["Rooms","Service","Location","Value"]
,[]
```

Which is impossible to parse using php json_decode() function. Is there any library or something which will allow me to convert this to a regular json so that my task will be easier ? Otherwise I know I have to write regular expression.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: is that an array of arrays? Can you normalize it? Means something like this `array(name, array(work, array(something))`. As nothing could be meaningfully inferred from the date in your OP

Comment: that's the problem...I have pasted the actual data which I get...I too can't figure out how is it formatted ?

Comment: It is not properly nested even. Regex is the only solution if you wanna extract data. What actually you want to extract out of it?

Comment: If [["oppl.lr",[,,,,,,,,,,,[[,"A Google User"],"",""],""]]] be the data...then is it possible ? I want to get these data for my project.

Comment: Might be mad soln but Ya This is a valid javascript array :P try `console.log([["oppl.lr",[,,,,,,,,,,,[[,"A Google User"],"",""],""]]])` then you can use `for..in` kind of loops. Or `json encode` the same and send it back to your server

Comment: To make it a valid php array it should be `$arr = [["oppl.lr",['','','','','','',[['',"A Google User"],"",""],""]]];`

Comment: but how can i do this from my data ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14328/discussion-between-tamil-and-tuhin-subhra-dey)

Comment: as we discussed `php eval worked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment. Incase your data is

`[["oppl.lr",[,,,,,,,,,,,[[,"A Google User"],"",""],""]]]`

If you can somehow send the data to client side. Then it is a valid javascript array.  Either you can process the data @client side or use

`JSON.stringify([["oppl.lr",[,,,,,,,,,,,[[,"A Google User"],"",""],""]]]);`

and send the data back to server as

`"[["oppl.lr",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[[null,"A Google User"],"",""],""]]]"`

Else via php you can use this function

```
function getValidArray($input) {
   $input = str_replace(",,", ',"",', $input);
   $input = str_replace(",,", ',"",', $input);
   $input = str_replace("[,", '["",', $input);
   return eval("return $input;");
}
```

You can optimize the above function as per the need.

Comment: in getValidArray function first two lines are identical....what's the need of this... ?

Comment: what was the input u gave? I tested only for ur input. I have clearly mentioned `You can optimize the above function as per the need` but this is just an idea. So, Consider rewriting if you have varied input. Coz ur OP clearly mentions give any ideas ;)

Comment: what you have mentioned above is the input. Anyway I will try myself. Thanks 4 ur time.

Comment: Consider upvoting or accepting if it really helped you :) My input was `'[["oppl.lr",[,,,,,,,,,,,[[,"A Google User"],"",""],""]]]'` Make sure you have that single quote around the input.

Comment: Doesn't work...no need of eval function...I also mentioned in my question if I need to write regular expression...

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0DxbGc Check this the same code. You should be using php version 5.4 to execute.